# What am I getting wrong on malloc and realloc understanding?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I was trying to make an array that would resize whilst the program is running. I have come to knowledge of malloc and realloc functions but it seems I'm getting something wrong apparently. Here's the function that I wrote that creates an array based on how many cycles is the loop making.

```
int* flexibleArray() {
    int *arrayFlex = NULL;
    int number=0, cnt=0;
    while (number!=-1) {
        printf("\nInsert the variable: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number==-1){
            break;
        }
        cnt+=1;
        arrayFlex = realloc(arrayFlex, cnt * sizeof(int));
        arrayFlex[cnt-1] = number;
    }
    return arrayFlex;
}
```

I tried to read the documentation I found on the internet about it, I can't then retrieve the new array after the reallocation.

```
int *array;
    array = flexibleArray();
    int arraySize = (sizeof(array))/(sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
```

basically this is where I'm testing the function to see if it does what it should.

I'm new to C, sorry guys.
Thanks

Comment: `malloc(0);` ??

Comment: ... is valid, albeit not useful here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes I removed the malloc line that was actually useless. I changed the pointers, perhaps it should have been like this?

Comment: Your function is (still) declared to return an `int`, whereas you seem to want it to return a pointer.

Comment: So how should I return the actual array. I mean let the function return it

Comment: If you want to return an `int *` then do so (and declare so).  But also, your revised code attempts to `realloc()` the space pointed to be `arrayFlex` when that pointer has not been initialized.  It's unclear why you're accepting it as a parameter at all -- I'd just make it a local variable, suitably initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: You're right passing the variable was completely useless, so actually following your corrections this should be the final one, I guess

Comment: This: `int arraySize = (sizeof(array))/(sizeof(int));` does not do what you think it does. (What it most likely does is to always return 2. On any given platform, it always returns the same small number, usually one or two.) There is no way to get C to tell you the current size of a dynamically resized array, so you'll have to return the size as well as the pointer.

Comment: Regarding the edit: `int flexArray = NULL` is missing the semicolon and has the wrong name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
int* flexibleArray() {                                                          
    int *arrayFlex = NULL;                 // needs to be a pointer             
    int number=0, cnt=0;                                                        
    while (number!=-1) {                                                        
        printf("\nInsert the variable: ");                                      
        scanf("%d", &number);                                                   
        if (number==-1){                                                        
            break;                                                              
        }                                                                       
        cnt+=1;                                                                 
        arrayFlex = realloc(arrayFlex, cnt * sizeof(int));                      
        arrayFlex[cnt-1] = number;                                              
    }                                                                           
    return arrayFlex;                                                           
}
```

EDIT: fixed typos.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the pointer on flexArray. I guess I should practice a little bit more with pointers that in this case they were just confusing me

Comment: @L_Cleo no worries, pointers are a bit confusing. What compiler are you using, btw? Most compilers will have an option to turn on more warnings, which are really helpful especially when learning C.

Comment: I usually use Xcode, because I'm learning swift on my own too, but apparently I have to study C in College so I was simply trying to compile via terminal as it would be in the exam

Comment: what command do you use for compiling on the terminal? @L_Cleo

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've fixed the typos. It will now compile.

Comment: @L_Cleo I recommend using `clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror` in order to compile, instead of `clang`. This will turn on lots of extra warnings, which will help you in lots of cases (like the one in your question).